# Importing library in Android Studio

Tags: android, import, android-studio, parse-platform

I have little experience with importing libraries. I am using Android Studio, and am trying to use parse.com's library with no luck. I followed these [instructions](https://parse.com/questions/parse-library-in-android-studio), and tried a few other things when that didn't work. Please help me out. Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks for your time.

This is my MainActivity where I would initialize my Parse client key: 
[image: MainActivity]

Project Structure showing I have imported the libraries:
[image: Project Structure]
[image]

**UPDATE**
Gradle:
[image]
**UPDATE:**
When I try to Build, I get this error:    `Gradle: error: package com.parse does not exist`
When I try cleaning through command prompt[image]

Comment: Does the jar come as a library or just a jar file?

Comment: It came as `Parse-1.3.1-javadoc`. So a Library?

Comment: This is one of the problems of using android studio at the moment. The  project properties does not yet automate everything for you and so you have to set all gradle stuff up manually.

Comment: Ok, I searched that a bit cause I got that error (see update). I tried putting it in the gradle but had no luck, do you know the steps to do this?

Comment: Ok, just go to android studio and go to build and press rebuild project and then make project once the rebuild is done.

Comment: Still getting 2 errors after `Make Project`:`Gradle: Execution failed for task ':ClashMMA:compileDebug'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.` `Gradle: error: package com.parse does not exist`,

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34309/discussion-between-thepolodoc-and-binghammer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Put the jar  into the libs folder
2. Right click it and hit 'Add as library'
3. Ensure that compile files('libs/~~~~~~~~.jar') is in your build.gradle file
4. Do a clean build (You can do this easily in android studio but just as a better method, go to your project folder using windows explorer and open a Command window there by right clicking the folder while holding shift and type gradlew build.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer of @ThePoloDoc and for your update Command Prompt image, you need to do the following to clear that error:

1. Go to Control Panel -> System -> Right Side see for Advanced System settings
2. Select Environmental Variables
3. In the new window, search for the PATH variable. Add the java installation folder something similar to `C:\PATH_TO_JDK\bin`

Replace the `PATH_TO_JDK` with the installation of your java directory
Try opening the command prompt and you'll see the error gone.

**UPDATE:**
I have got a doubt in your question. Why do you manually compile gradle? I use Android Studio. But I always click the `Sync Project with Gradle Files` button on the top. It does everything for me